# Writing a modular ODE solver with user defined function

Tags: r, desolve

I am writing an exercise for master students, I want them to be able to type an ODE system and get it automatically evaluated with deSolve.

The problem I have now is defining the function to be evaluated in R dynamically, based on user input. Let's say I want to read from a text file ODE.txt, which contains the ODE system in the same syntax I would use writing it directly in there:

```
  ##function (differential form)
  ODEfun <- function(time=seq(1:times_range), state=state, parms=parms) {
    
    with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {
      
      source("ODE.txt")

    })
  }
  
  ## Solve using ode (General Solver for Ordinary Differential Equations)
  out <- ode(y = init, time = seq(1:times_range), func = ODEfun, parms = parameters)
```

The ODE.txt file:

```
      .S=-b*S*I
      .I <-  b * S * I - g * I
      .R <-                 g * I
   return(list(c(.S, .I, .R)))
```

(it contains the example system I am starting with, I have written the functions to process it already)

And the error:

```
Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'b' not found
```

The error is quite much the same whatever I try (I tried a combination of  `eval(parse(` ,  `evaluate` , etc...

Does anyone have any idea of how to build this thing?
Thanks in any case!

Comment: The error is not reproducible, we're missing the values of `init` and `parameters`.

Comment: and the `library` statement(s) are missing too.  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page regarding asking questions.

Comment: Note that seq(1:n) should be 1:n or seq(n).  Also a function definition cannot have an default argument value that refers to itself, i.e. parms = parrms is not allowed in a function definition because it is circular.  There are undoubtedly other problems too but we can't tell without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way.

Have the function `ODEfun` have an extra argument, `equations` to become the text file's contents. In the function replace `source` by `eval(parse())`. Before the `ode` call read the text file into a variable, in the case below `eqs`, and pass that variable as the extra argument's value.

The parameters' and initial values were taken from this [RPubs post](https://rpubs.com/choisy/sir).

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
-- Thomas Lumley
R-help (February 2005)).

```
##function (differential form)
ODEfun <- function(time=seq(1:times_range), state=state, parms=parms, equations) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {
    
    eval(parse(text = equations))
    
  })
}

parameters <- c(
  b  = 0.004, # infectious contact rate (/person/day)
  g = 0.5    # recovery rate (/day)
)
init <- c(
  S = 999,  # number of susceptibles at time = 0
  I =   1,  # number of infectious at time = 0
  R =   0   # number of recovered (and immune) at time = 0
)
times_range <- 10

eqs <- readLines("ODE.txt")
## Solve using ode (General Solver for Ordinary Differential Equations)
out <- ode(y = init, time = 1:times_range, func = ODEfun, parms = parameters, equations = eqs)

out
#   time           S         I          R
#1     1 999.0000000   1.00000   0.000000
#2     2 963.7055522  31.79832   4.496128
#3     3 461.5686153 441.91586  96.515523
#4     4  46.1563274 569.50414 384.339532
#5     5   7.0358787 373.49828 619.465843
#6     6   2.1489403 230.12932 767.721743
#7     7   1.0390925 140.41084 858.550071
#8     8   0.6674074  85.44478 913.887809
#9     9   0.5098627  51.94497 947.545167
#10   10   0.4328912  31.56515 968.001963
```

### Edit

Here is the code Gabor Grothendiek's comment, slightly edited. The function is named `ODEfun2` and its body goes in a separate vector. The results are `identical` to the results above.

```
ODEfun2 <- function(time, state, parms) {} # empty body

fun_body <- c(
  "with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {", 
  eqs, 
  "})"
)

body(ODEfun2) <- parse(text = fun_body)
out2 <- ode(y = init, time = 1:times_range, func = ODEfun2, parms = parameters)

identical(out, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

### However...

Remeber:

```
fortunes::fortune(106)

#If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#   -- Thomas Lumley
#      R-help (February 2005)
```

Comment: Good idea. One variation would be this which avoids parsing and evaluating eqs on each  call to ODEfun. `ODEfun <- function(time, state, parms) {}; 
body(ODEfun) <- parse(text = c("with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {", eqs, "})"));
out <- ode(y = init, time = 1:times_range, func = ODEfun, parms = parameters)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, thanks. Added to the answer.

Comment: Another approach is provided by the [rodeo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rodeo) package. Here even complex systems of equations can be organized as tables (csv, xlsx, ods) from which rodeo generates fast Fortran code and an R interface to deSolve.